# Formulario a Objeto en Angular

Tags: angular, formularios

Usando formularios reactivos en Angular, cual sería la inversa de patchValue?

```
this.form.patchValue(this.unobjeto);
```

Quiero decir, como hago para obtener todos los campos del formulario y asignarlos a un objeto, para luego enviarlo a la Api para almacenarlo en la BD, gracias.

Comment: Usas un FormGroup?

Comment: Si, uso FormGroup

Comment: Entonces solo usa el nombre del formgroup seguido del value console.log(formGroupName.value);

Comment: Exacto asi como dijo @JeffersonCuji obtienes el objeto de tu form, al igual puedes usar el `.getRawValue()` que este de vuelve todos los valores hasta el de los campos `disabled`. [getRawValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer `this.form.value` y obtendrás todos los valores que no estén deshabilitados.

Comment: Gracias, use this.form.value y lo asigne al objeto asi:
 this.entidad=this.form.value;

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `this.form.get('name')` para obtener el value de cada uno de los campos de tu formulario, donde 'name' es el form control name.

**Ejemplo:**

`this.form.get('phone')` para obtener el número de teléfono ingresado en el formulario.

Te comparto el apartado de la documentación donde lo explican:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms

Comment: claro, pero eso lo hace campo a campo, quisiera hacerlo en un solo paso como se hace con patchValue.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es crear una función que controle el **Form**.

Algo así:

```js
get f () { return this.form.controls; }
```

Después, cuando quieras modificar algo del formulario solo llamas la función, por ejemplo algo así:

```js
this.f.id.setValue(2);
```

Y si es un texto le colocas las '', algo así:

```js
this.f.id.nombre.setValue('juan');
```

En el caso de que tengas una variable:

```js
public variable = 'juan';
```

Quedaría así:

```js
this.f.nombre.setValue(this.variable);
```

Pero la forma más directa creo yo, quizás esté en un error, es:

```js
this.form.value.id;
```

Como comentaron anteriormente.